is there a way to get Langchain pandas dataframe agent to query using "similar" words rather than "exact" words
Creating a simple events guide chatbot using langchain csv or pandas dataframe, both have the same issue.
In order to get a good response, you must ask a very specific question using the exact wording from the data set.  This is problematic for simple chat since the user doesn't really know the exact wording contained in the dataset.
I have not see a way where you can tweak the pandas query to look at "similar" words that "contain" the keywords from the prompt...
dataset example of the row containing the info about helicopter tours in Vegas:
Las Vegas Strip Helicopter tour,Self-guided,3500 Las Vegas blvd,Fun in Vegas,March-24,7:00 AM,9:00 AM,

create agent:


 88 df = pd.read_csv("csv-files/csv.csv")
 89
 90
 91 agent = create_pandas_dataframe_agent(
 92     local_llm,
 93     df,
 94     verbose=True,
 95 #    agent_type=AgentType.ZERO_SHOT_REACT_DESCRIPTION,  ### only zero shot available, otherwise must use openAI functions
 96 )
 97


asking a general question about an event related to helicopter tours. 



115 res = agent.invoke("Is there any event related to helicopter tours?")
116 print(res)
117
118


response:

> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:2 for open-end generation.
Thought: I need to check if there is any event in the dataframe with the word 'helicopter' in the Event Name column.
Action: python_repl_ast
Action Input: df[df['Event Name'].str.contains('helicopter')]Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Event Name, Host, Location, Event Category, Date, Time start, Time end, Unnamed: 7]
Index: []Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:2 for open-end generation.

There is no event related to helicopter tours in the dataframe.
Final Answer: No, there is no event related to helicopter tours in the dataframe.


^^^^^^^^^   so that is incorrect, the str.contains query actually DOES contain the word helicopter..
If I specifically ask it a question with the exact wording or about some other column, then it will return a response but the prompt has to be very carefully planned...  It can find the actual event..
> Entering new AgentExecutor chain...
Setting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:2 for open-end generation.
Thought: I need to find the event that has the location '3500 Las Vegas blvd'.
Action: python_repl_ast
Action Input: df[df['Location'] == '3500 Las Vegas blvd'].head()                         Event Name         Host             Location Event Category      Date Time start Time end  Unnamed: 7
37  Las Vegas Strip Helicopter tour  Self-guided  3500 Las Vegas blvd   Fun in Vegas  March-24    7:00 AM  9:00 AM         NaNSetting `pad_token_id` to `eos_token_id`:2 for open-end generation.
 I now know the final answer
Final Answer: The event 'Las Vegas Strip Helicopter tour' is located at 3500 Las Vegas blvd.

> Finished chain.
{'input': 'Which event is located at 3500 Las Vegas blvd?', 'output': "The event 'Las Vegas Strip Helicopter tour' is located at 3500 Las Vegas blvd."}


The problem is that this is requiring exact wording..  Anyone have any ideas on how to better guide the CSV / Pandas dataframe agent to search for similar or "contains" queries?
thanks!!
